# Java: square brackets when declaring HashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, square-bracket

I'm trying to adapt code from [here](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/blob/master/modules/StatisticsPlugin/src/main/java/org/gephi/statistics/plugin/Modularity.java#L34) and I can't figure out why they've declared and instantiated their HashMaps using square brackets. Here's some simplified sample code:

```
class CommunityStructure {
    HashMap<Modularity.Community, Float>[] nodeConnectionsWeight;
    HashMap<Modularity.Community, Integer>[] nodeConnectionsCount;
    int N;
    ...

    CommunityStructure(Graph graph) {
    ...
    N = graph.getNodeCount();
    nodeConnectionsWeight = new HashMap[N];
    }
    ...
}
```

I thought square brackets were mainly meant for arrays, so I was confused to see them applied to Maps as well.

Comment: You can create array of any `Object`. In this case, its `HashMap<Modularity.Community, Float>`

Comment: To Java, a `Map` is not special in any way. It's just another reference type, just like `String`, `Integer`, `Socket`, `Random`, `Foo`, `Bar`, etc. There is no special notation for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"They" are declaring arrays of `HashMap`s.

This is perfectly legit.

Each array will contain a number of instances of `HashMap<Modularity.Community, Float>`  (or `Integer` as map value in the second variable).

Comment: Got it. Never seen an array of Maps before. Thanks!

Comment: its rare however you will be seeing lot of arrays like array of map and map of array :-). you should accept the answer so other person don't put effort in same thing.

Comment: Yeah I've tried to hit "accept" but it says I need to wait 6 minutes. Awkward.